How to reference multiple named cells or range in one query
My company requires an excel sheet to calculate multiple factors for employees. I currently have this set up to calculate for one employee at a time by have a named cell, EMPID, which is thrown into Power Query to automatically calculate this information. However, this method only allows one employee's information to be ran at a time and there are occasions where 10+ employees will need to be ran.
The current set up is:

named cell is created into a query
this query is referenced by 3 SQL queries in Power Query to automatically grab the employee's information
all queries are merged into 1 excel table output

I previously had it set up to run multiple employees at the same time by having the employee entered as a table, not a named cell, but in order for the SQL queries to get the information, I would need to merge the table within each query (so, 3 times + the final output). This caused the refresh time to be 1 minute +, depending on the amount of employees.
I've attempted to do this as a named range, but the data is automatically thrown into a table - which can't be used in SQL as I'm referencing the data with the & operator
Current use:

sql code xyv employid = '" & EID & "' abc code

The & cannot be used with a table or text type.

Assuming you have a table of EIDs in Power Query named TableEIDs similar to this:



EID




a1


b2


c3



Right click on that query and select Reference. Then in the formula bar, update it to:
= "'" & Text.Combine(TableEIDs[EID], "','") & "'"

This will give you a text query looking like:
'a1','b2','c3'

You can now use this in your SQL like:
sql code xyv employid IN (" & theReferenceQueryText & ") ....

